# Is it possible to set a border to overlay (like in photoshop)

Tags: c#, wpf, border, overlay

I am having a quite exotic question:
I am currently working on a "borderless" WPF Application. I successfully removed the standard windows window controls and added my own. Now I wanted to add a border to the programm. But I don't want the border to have specifc color, I want it to be in some kind of overlay mode like when you set a layer in photoshop to overlay. You can see what I mean in an example:

[image: Photoshop Mookup]

I really want it to look like on the left. But unfortunately I really have no idea how. 
Basically what the overlay does is that it takes the background color and it makes it a bit darker.
Do you have any suggestions what I could do?

Edit: Here is a better picture of the effect

[Photoshop Mookup2 http://img.xrmb2.net/images/243147.png](http://img.xrmb2.net/images/243147.png)

Edit2 : So, as a short explanation because it may not be as clear as I have hoped: I am not talking about a semi-transparency. I know how to do that. The right box in both images uses that. It has a black-semitransparent look. While on the left I set the border to "overlay" mode. As you can see it gets darker but also a bit stronger in color.

Comment: Layering is what Grids were made for.  Create a border layer and set the fill to a low opacity.  Should be straight-forward unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `Transparent` brush?:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="5">
    ...
</Border>
```

UPDATE >>>

Oh, hold on... I see what you want... try this instead with a semi opaque `brush:

```
<Border BorderBrush="3F000000" BorderThickness="5">
    ...
</Border>
```

You can adjust the darkness of the `Border`, by changing the first two hexadecimal characters: `3F`.

UPDATE >>>

I believe that this *is* the correct solution. As I said last:

> You can adjust the darkness of the `Border`, by changing the first two hexadecimal characters

So just try different values until you get the right balance of opacity. Start with hardly visible black and then increase the opacity until you get it right:

```
<Border BorderBrush="08000000" BorderThickness="5">
    ...
</Border>
...
<Border BorderBrush="0F000000" BorderThickness="5">
    ...
</Border>
...
<Border BorderBrush="1F000000" BorderThickness="5">
    ...
</Border>
...
<Border BorderBrush="2F000000" BorderThickness="5">
    ...
</Border>
```

If none of these values look quite right still, then use a semi-opaque white instead:

```
<Border BorderBrush="2FFFFFFF" BorderThickness="5">
    ...
</Border>
```

Comment: Well thank you so far but this won't quite do the trick. I mean maybe I wasn't precise enough. But if you look at the picture I posted you can see that the color of the background is kind of emphasized though the overlay effect. Here is another picture that displays the difference between overlay and a simple semi-transparent border. On the right you see what happens if you use a semi-transparent border while on the left you see an overlay effect.

[Click me](http://img.xrmb2.net/images/243147.png)